# Docker Compose - Save Keycloak Configurations?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I'm running my Flask and Keycloak Service using Docker Compose. My goal is that only the flask service has access to the keycloak service. I did this by simply exposing the keycloak and creating links. However, I used to use port 8080:8080 and access it with host, creating realm and client on keycloak. I was using these realm and client secret settings in my Flask service. These settings I created are deleted in the next docker-compose up command, and I can't create these requirements because I don't have access to this service. How can I create these settings on 8080:8080 (when I have access) and then use permanently on next runs? I tried creating a volume but I didn't manage it.

docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - keycloak:kc
    depends_on:
      - keycloak
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak:13.0.1
    volumes:
      - .:/keycloak
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by exporting keycloak config and importing to the keycloak volume. For those who has the same problem, put realm_export.json in to imports folder then add this codes to docker-compose file

```
keycloak:
    volumes:
      - ./imports:/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports
    container_name: keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak:13.0.1
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_IMPORT: /opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/realm-export.json -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
```